# How can i learn jslibs quickly? Reactjs,AngularJS, node, es6, babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

I like to explore new things, I create my own page with MEAN, I also try to learn **ES6** and **react** to create new web at the same time. But sometimes i feel so confuse about those things, all things messed up together. So lots of api i need to learn to remeber. Do anybody have a good idea to tell me how to handle all those things clear?

Comment: This is off-topic here, but given that you first say you want to learn "quickly" and then say you get confused, it means you're going too fast. Learn one thing at a time, not everything at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should google your question,not post here. There are lots of blog posted about your topic.For learning new things, you need follow some examples to learn. And try to talk with somebody else, learn from somebody. Watch videos about your interesting topic. There are also some conf video in youtube, you can check it out.